# how to find at runtime if an action will fire an effect or what effects are triggered by which actions?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am trying to find a way to know if an action will trigger an effect at runtime.

I can see the Effects Class at runtime and I can see the created effects in the class members as well but I have no idea how to find out the action that may trigger the effect before the effect is fired.

Any ideas if this is even possible? I ask this because I could use one effect for each action but sometimes actions will fire different effects and many effects can be fired by two different actions, the idea is to know before changing state if an effect may occur or not.

FYI: I am not implementing this anywhere I am just trying to understand the tool better.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why would you need this information at runtime? Is it for an application feature or for debugging reasons?

Comment: just for debugging, I am trying to draw a redux/ngrx store as a state machine and state machine you can define actions/effects and provide implementation later. and you can look at the machine and see at any given future states or transitions what effects might trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whomever interested, I think you can check effects before by creating then from within the effect class constructor, and reading the effects from an Object/Map. with apply method I can avoid repeating some of the operators in the effect.

```
const TodoStateEffects = {
  $QueryTodo: {
    effect: () => [
      filter(([action, state, context]) => state === 'QueryTodo'),
      map(([action, state, context]) =>
        ...
      ),
    ],
  },
};
```

```
@Injectable()
export class TodoEffects {
  constructor(private actions$: Actions, store: Store) {
     Object.keys(TodoStateEffects).forEach((k) => {
      (this[k] = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$.pipe.apply(this.actions$, [
          concatLatestFrom(() => [
            store.select(selectState),
            store.select(selectContext),
          ]),
          distinctUntilChanged(
            ([pAction, pState], [cAction, cState]) => pState === cState
          ),
          ...TodoStateEffects[k].effect(),
        ])
      )),
        TodoStateEffects[k]?.option;
    });
  }
}
```

no idea if this can cause issues. But again, the point was to understand the tools and play around it. Anyhow here it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this for debugging purposes, you can use [ngrx store devtools](https://ngrx.io/guide/store-devtools), it also has a visualization tool. You can also use [meta reducers](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/metareducers) for the purpose of debugging, as described in the example

Comment: I thought meta reducers would help but I was not able to see how I can find the effect an action might trigger from a meta reducer. Neither from the devtools. I know I can just at the code but again that is static analysis. Another way is to create a map for the effects so I can read them without running the effect,  but that duplicates the code.